# Load particular slide (DIV) based on navigation bar and hide the previous slide (DIV)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I asked a question a while ago with something similar but fixed the problem myself, I'm trying to get back into web design again as a hobby but I'm stumped.

I'm trying to create a sort of storybook/powerpoint effect, when next is pressed it'll load the next div (.slide) and the previous slide will close.

```
Here's a code pen of what I have: (buggy on codepen for some reason)
```

As you can see, it's functional but not very effective. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm struggling. I'm not sure why it's acting broken on the codepen but works on browsers (probably a bad sign) but you can see the how it functions.

However I want to add more functionality/practicality to it and want to be able to navigate to particular slides with the Navigation sidebar. The way I've done it means that the slide can't really be specified since it's set to active using the previous/next buttons.

Any sort of help would be great, some available tutorials or previous questions with the same desired effect (I've tried finding something) or just pointing me in the right direction would be great (I wanna make sure I understand)

Comment: first of all with css "display: none". then "display: block". so it must be all closed in the code where it first runs

Comment: @Minan sorry I'm a bit confused what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand. This is the answer you've been looking for. https://codepen.io/Minan/pen/xMXgBZ.

Comment: @Minan hey man that's great. I understand the first part, but I'm a bit confused about what
 ('.maincontainer .slide:eq('+ ($(this).index() - 1) +')');
 means, could you explain it to me? (you're awesome!)

Comment: this gives the order number of the clicked element. "$(this).index()". Here I find the element to select and add "active" class according to their order. So this is picky. like "nth-child".